# Xcode stuck at loading profiles

Tags: xcode

I did not renew my paid Apple developer account subscription, thus my account was downgraded to a free developer account. Since then, the Account under Xcodes `Preferences > Accounts` tab won't load any profiles (not even the Xcode managed ones) and is stuck at `Loading...` (see screenshot). Any Ideas what's going on? A free account should still be able to deploy to devices according to Apple.

[image: Profile List]

Happens in Xcode 8 & 9 on Sierra

Comment: Do one thing , just clear everything and remove apple id and then again add using + , now try to download profile , it will show you and you can create and deploy to your application into your iphone for short period of time

Comment: I did this already several times... still same issue.

Comment: I faced same issue and i did same way or you can use other free apple id once

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about support at Apple's site, and not a programming question as defined in the [help] guidelines. We cannot provide support for a third-party site here.

Comment: This is still happening 2021